# Node JS Express route only accessible on a button click

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

I was wondering if it was possible to make an express route only accessible after a button click? I don't want a user to be able to enter in the route in the url bar and access it, but only be able to access it after a certain button is clicked. Just wondering if thats possible and if it is, if anyone has an example that would be great! Thanks!

Comment: The URL bar uses GET requests, so if you make the route only accessible through a POST request, then it shouldn't be possible to access it through the URL bar.

Comment: Why don't you use just add an authentication? You can check the cookie, bearer token etc..

Comment: If you just want to block access from a browser. @Geshode suggestion is simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely possible, but you have to change the request type to `POST` instead of `GET`. If you're using a `POST` request, users will not be able to access your endpoint via URL.

For example, let's say you have this button.

```html
<button class="my_button">To restricted endpoint</button>
```

Simply define a JavaScript script to run when you have clicked that button.

```js
const myButton = document.querySelector(".my_button");

if (myButton) {
  myButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    // perform your request here, either with fetch or axios...
  });
}
```

You're done.